# Java compare this class to that class for equality

Tags: java, compare, equality

My assignment is to override the method equals().  I have a few concerns using `Stack12<E> that = (Stack12<E>)o;` and `o instanceof Stack12`. I am wonder are they bad practice, especially how I using `that` in the for-loop feels a little not right to me.

Is there another way to compare the this class to some other object? Or is my compare method robust enough?

```
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o){
  if(o == this) return true;
  if(o == null || !(o instanceof Stack12)){
     return false;
  }

  Stack12<E> that = (Stack12<E>)o;
  if(this.size != that.size || this.capacity != that.capacity ){
     return false;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < this.size; i++){
     if( that.stack[i] != this.stack[i] ){
        return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
 }
```

Comment: I feel uncomfortable casting an object to a generic type. And I think I read somewhere using instanceof is a bad practice in Java.

Comment: The only caveat I'd add is that whenever you override `equals(...)`, you will also want to override `hashCode()`. Oops, I do in fact see one major issue -- answer posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One caveat I'd add is that whenever you override `equals(...)`, you will also want to override `hashCode()`. I agree that seeing instanceof overused makes me worry about code smell, but I think that you have no choice but to use instanceof in this situation. As for casting to generic type, I may be wrong, but at run-time, generics really don't exist, so it may be moot.

One potentially major issue I see though is that you're using `==` in your for loop. If your stack array uses objects, you should use `equals(...)` inside the loop. The fact that your class is generic suggests that the stack array does hold objects, but I'm not sure since we don't see this.

Comment: Thank you for the equals(...) tip

Comment: @Jack: You're welcome, but please note that this is not an issue if stack holds primitives.

Comment: The o == null is unnecessary.  instanceof will always be false for null.

Comment: Oh another question. After running the code in junit tester there is one case that fails. Which is when I have something like Stack<Integer> s1 = new blah blah; Stack<String> s2 = blah blah.  The test shows they are equal. How do I test the type of the generic?

Comment: @Jack: I'm not sure that you can due to type erasure.